# XQuery: best way to convert node sequence to array

Tags: saxon, xquery-3.0

I am using Saxon, version 9.8.0.6 with this input document:

```
<simple>
  <hello>Hello World!</hello>
  <number>42</number>
  <keyword>abc</keyword>
  <keyword>def</keyword>
  <keyword>ghi</keyword>
</simple>
```

And this query

```
xquery version "3.1";
fn:serialize(map{
  'greeting': data(/simple/hello),
  'number': number(/simple/number),
  'keywords': array{ for $k in /simple/keyword return data($k) }
}, map{'method':'json', 'indent':true()})
```

Output is (as expected):

```
{
  "number":42,
  "keywords": [
    "abc",
    "def",
    "ghi"
   ],
  "greeting":"Hello World!"
 }
```

Question:

`'keywords': array{ for $k in /simple/keyword return data($k) }` seems a little clumsy for me. Is this the way to do it? Any suggestions for improving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce

```
array{ for $k in /simple/keyword return data($k) }
```

to

```
array{data(/simple/keyword)}
```